# T-SQL removing multiple characters from string after delimiters

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

String that passes to stored procedure as variable looks like this:

```
'10273955=1|10142823=5|10664263=10|10134335=3|10046639=3|10334724=25|10334725=100'
```

I'm looking for a fast way to parse it to:

```
'10273955|10142823|10664263|10134335|10046639|10334724|10334725'
```

SQL server is 2016

Comment: If you need to maintain the original order, then SQL Server is not the best tool for doing this.  You need regex replacement, which SQL Server does not support.  If you don't care about the order, and you using a recent version of SQL Server, then `STRING_SPLIT` might be workable.

Comment: Why don't you use a table variable?   They've been around since SQL Server 2000 and suit your use case better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion was this:

A *mockup table* to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(250));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('10273955=1|10142823=5|10664263=10|10134335=3|10046639=3|10334724=25|10334725=100');
```

--The query

```
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.YourString
      ,A.CastedToXml
      ,REPLACE(A.CastedToXml.query('data(/x/y[1])').value('.','varchar(150)'),' ','|')
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x><y>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(t.YourString,'|','</y></x><x><y>'),'=','</y><y>') + '</y></x>' AS XML)) A(CastedToXml);
```

The result

```
10273955|10142823|10664263|10134335|10046639|10334724|10334725
```

The idea in short:

The `APPLY` will use some replacements to transform a double-separated XML in one go. It will look like this:

```
<x>
  <y>10273955</y>
  <y>1</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10142823</y>
  <y>5</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10664263</y>
  <y>10</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10134335</y>
  <y>3</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10046639</y>
  <y>3</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10334724</y>
  <y>25</y>
</x>
<x>
  <y>10334725</y>
  <y>100</y>
</x>
```

The trick is the usage of XQuery's `data()`, which returns all values in the XPath as **blank** separated fragments. Using a XPath of `/x/y[1]` tells the engine: *Pick each `<x>` and the **first** `<y>` you find in there!*.

Btw: In XML the sort order is fix. So the returned string will not change this order.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) and `FOR XML PATH` (as 2017 introduces `STRING_AGG`) you could do this and retain the ordering, but the real solution is to stop storing delimited delimited data (yes, I did mean to say delimited twice, as it's `|` and `=` delimited) in your tables...

```
SELECT YT.YourColumn,
       STUFF((SELECT '|' + LEFT(DS.Item,CHARINDEX('=',DS.item)-1)
              FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.YourColumn,'|') DS
              ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(8000)'),1,1,'') AS NewColumn        
FROM (VALUES('10273955=1|10142823=5|10664263=10|10134335=3|10046639=3|10334724=25|10334725=100'))YT(YourColumn)
```

But, like i said, fix your design. you could do that with `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD` again:

```
SELECT DS1.ItemNumber AS ID,
       CONVERT(int,MAX(CASE DS2.ItemNumber WHEN 1 THEN DS2.Item END)) AS LongNumber,
       CONVERT(int,MAX(CASE DS2.ItemNumber WHEN 2 THEN DS2.Item END)) AS ShortNumber
FROM (VALUES('10273955=1|10142823=5|10664263=10|10134335=3|10046639=3|10334724=25|10334725=100'))YT(YourColumn)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.YourColumn,'|') DS1
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(DS1.Item,'=') DS2
GROUP BY DS1.ItemNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Ngrams8k you could do this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 
  '10273955=1|10142823=5|10664263=10|10134335=3|10046639=3|10334724=25|10334725=100';

SELECT NewString = 
(
  SELECT CASE SIGN(s.position) WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ng.token END
  FROM   dbo.NGrams8k(@string,1) AS ng
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT ng.position, nxt.Pos, ln=nxt.Pos-ng.position
    FROM   dbo.ngrams8k(@string,1) AS ng
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
      ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('|',@string, ng.position+1),0),LEN(@string)+1))) AS nxt(Pos)
    WHERE  ng.token = '='
  ) AS s ON ng.position BETWEEN s.position AND s.pos-1
  ORDER BY ng.position ASC
  FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

**Returns:**

```
NewString
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10273955|10142823|10664263|10134335|10046639|10334724|10334725
```